# Доступность таблицы при запущенной форме | VBA, EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

Как сделать доступной таблицу, при запущенной форме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*UserForm* может быть открыта в модальном или немодальном режиме. При модальном доступ к листу *Excel* закрыт, при немодальном с листом можно работать.

Параметр, отвечающий за модальность, можно задать в параметрах формы:

*Properties (F4)-Alpfabetic-ShowModal*

или

*Properties (F4)-Categorized-Behavior-ShowModal*

При *ShowModal = False* с листом можно работать.